# How to ensure Firebase database security rules that a message can't be created in the past?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In a messaging iOS app I am working on, I would like to ensure that a user cannot send a message to another user in the future.

The timestamp is created on the server using

```
    [".sv": "timestamp"]
```

I just need clarification on whether I should use < now (less than)  or <= now (less than and equal to) for my database rule. The documentation says the [former](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#now) but would the message timestamp not be equal to the server's current time for a split millisecond when it is written?? or is that a misinterpretation of how the timestamp value is created and inserted in the database as once the value is created there will always be a time difference for when it is then inserted??

```
   "timestamp": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() < now" },
   "timestamp": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() <= now" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, using

`".validate": "newData.val() <= now"`

instead of

`".validate": "newData.val() < now"`

does not have much of an impact (if at all) on the functionality of most programs, since allowing a user to write a couple milliseconds in the future is not usually a problem.

The former does, though, handle for the case you mentioned (the message being written at current server time), so regardless of how things work internally with Firebase, using the `<=` comparison is probably objectively the better option.

In addition, you may want to add another check for pre-dated messages such as this:

`".validate": "newData.val() <= now && newData.val() >= now - 60000"`

Which prevents users from writing anything more than 60 seconds in the past. The high interval is to allow for lag and other anomalies, but you can adjust it to whatever suits you.